# Nginx is not proxying Gunicorn

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my Flask project using Gunicorn and Nginx but I'm still struggling.

#### /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn3.service

```
[Unit] Description=Gunicorn service After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=adm 
WorkingDirectory=/home/project/
Environment="PATH=/home/project/env/bin" 
ExecStart=/home/project/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:cima.sock -m 007 run:app

[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I check if there's any problem, everything seems OK

```
>>sudo systemctl status gunicorn3
gunicorn3.service - Gunicorn service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn3.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-01-17 20:25:01 UTC; 18min ago
 Main PID: 18451 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn3.service
           ├─18451 /home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbot-grupo-3/chatbot-cima/chatbot-cima-back/cimaenv/bin/python3 /home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbo
           ├─18453 /home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbot-grupo-3/chatbot-cima/chatbot-cima-back/cimaenv/bin/python3 /home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbo
           ├─18454 /home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbot-grupo-3/chatbot-cima/chatbot-cima-back/cimaenv/bin/python3 /home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbo
           └─18456 /home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbot-grupo-3/chatbot-cima/chatbot-cima-back/cimaenv/bin/python3 /home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbo

Jan 17 20:25:01 acelerathon-cima-grupo-3 systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn service.
Jan 17 20:25:01 acelerathon-cima-grupo-3 gunicorn[18451]: [2020-01-17 20:25:01 +0000] [18451] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
Jan 17 20:25:01 acelerathon-cima-grupo-3 gunicorn[18451]: [2020-01-17 20:25:01 +0000] [18451] [INFO] Listening at: unix:cima.sock (18451)
Jan 17 20:25:01 acelerathon-cima-grupo-3 gunicorn[18451]: [2020-01-17 20:25:01 +0000] [18451] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Jan 17 20:25:01 acelerathon-cima-grupo-3 gunicorn[18451]: [2020-01-17 20:25:01 +0000] [18453] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18453
Jan 17 20:25:01 acelerathon-cima-grupo-3 gunicorn[18451]: [2020-01-17 20:25:01 +0000] [18454] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18454
Jan 17 20:25:01 acelerathon-cima-grupo-3 gunicorn[18451]: [2020-01-17 20:25:01 +0000] [18456] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18456
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/acelerathon_cima_grupo_3/chatbot-grupo-3/chatbot-cima/chatbot-cima-back/cima.sock;
    }
}
```

And then I checked for errors.

```
sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

So both services are OK, now when I access to **http://localhost I see the Nginx Home Page, not my Flask app home page**

I'm not sure why is not proxying

Answer (score 0):

Add `localhost` to `server_name` directive in Nginx. Nginx use this directive to match server block for each request and in your case `localhost` doesn't match `127.0.0.1` so it's server by default server.
May be this example will help to understand:

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        return 200 "At 127.0.0.1\n";
}

server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name localhost;
        return 200 "At localhost\n";
}

> curl -4 127.0.0.1:80
At 127.0.0.1
> curl -4 localhost:80
At localhost
```

Comment: Thanks now I have the same output as you but my app is hosted in VM and my url http://publicIP is still pointing to Ngnix home page
P.D. Why is neccesary the "-4" for curl?